How do you include someone with a space in their username in a post?
How do you include someone that has a space in their username in a comment or post? I've tried  @"User Name" & "@User Name", among others that haven't worked.

See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

"How do you include someone that has a space in their username in a comment or post? " - note that it will never have any kind of effect in a question or answer, it is restricted to comments. People tend to use the @ format in posts when they want to refer to a specific user name more because it is a web standard rather than that it actually has any kind of function.
